# NoSuchMethodError for google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng

Tags: android, google-maps, nosuchmethoderror

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError No direct method
>   (DD)V in class Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng; or its
>   super classes (declaration of
>   'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng' appears in base.apk)

I am getting this weird crash only on Samsung device SM-G610F (Nougat), it is working fine for other devices.

Gradle dependencies:

```
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.2"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.2"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.2"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.2"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.0.2"
```

Edit:

I have multiple-modules in the project, the base module contains most of the dependencies right now and **mutlidexing** is enabled.

> build.gradle file for base module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
android {

    compileSdkVersion compile_sdk_version
    buildToolsVersion build_tools_version

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion min_sdk_version
        targetSdkVersion target_sdk_version
        versionCode version_code
        versionName version_name
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled true
    }
}
dependencies {

    // Kotlin: Std Lib
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

    // Android Support
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$android_support"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$android_support"
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta5'
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$android_support"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$android_support"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$android_support"

    // Android Arch: LiveData
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:livedata:$android_arch"

    // Google Play Services
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$google_play_services"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:$google_play_services"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$google_play_services"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:$google_play_services"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:$google_play_services"
    implementation 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:1.14.5'
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
    implementation project(':ui')
}
```

**build.gradle for app module:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {

    compileSdkVersion compile_sdk_version
    buildToolsVersion build_tools_version

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion min_sdk_version
        targetSdkVersion target_sdk_version
        versionCode version_code
        versionName version_name
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        stage {
            dimension "mode"
            applicationId "com.example.abc.stage"
        }
        production {
            applicationId "com.example.abc"
        }
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled true
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    // Modules
    implementation project(':base')

    // MultiDex: 65k+ methods
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$android_support"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$android_support"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:livedata:$android_arch"

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: did you do multildexing ? also post your gradle full file here

Comment: Try to use the latest versions of these dependencies.

Comment: @quicklearner I am updated the post with the gradle file and yes mutlidexing is enabled.

Comment: ok dear let me check it , i will update you

Comment: did you try changing the version of google maps gradle?

Comment: Yes, I updated the version to latest but the issue persists.

Comment: also downgrade it to 10.0.2 something and try

Comment: did you find any solution yet ?

Comment: No luck till now..